# The Vowel Lengthening in 〜ます, 〜です

Tags: spoken-language, vowels

I notice over hundreds and hundreds of japanese's videos, anime and podcast that Japanese (mostly women but not only) tend in speech to length the vowel in the ending like 〜まーす, 〜でーす and so on.
I don't think it's technical or linguistic issue, but sorto of speech style, to soften a sentence or something like that.

So my question is: from a native speaker, what is your feeling about this? It's sound more "cute"? More soft? Or am i totally miss and it's something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a way of speaking is called 語尾をのばす, which can be used in several situations. Generally, talking without ー (i.e. the normal way of speaking/writing) can sound/look brusque, and as you mention, ー is kind of softening.

One typical case is conversations with children. For example, a primary school teacher talks to a classroom 準備できましたかー？(*Are you ready?*), then the pupils respond はーい. Similarly まーす or でーす is used by pupils or students talking to teachers (usually in context of responding or reporting something).

The lengthening is considered childish in business setting and should be avoided (e.g. [a web post](https://otonasalone.jp/61312/)). A woman (say in her 20s) speaking with too much ー would be regarded too coquettish(?) and a man talking too much that way would be just weird.

So your impression is not wrong, but it's mostly because there are lots of young girls in anime etc.

---

Another thing is 'vocative' usage of ー. This is not particularly childish or anything and can be used by people of all generations.

In English, sometimes people say *Hellooo* to reconfirm that nobody's there (calling to a house, for example) or *Heeyy* to attract the attention of a person who is a bit far off.

Similarly, when calling at some place or talking to a person at a distance, Japanese uses すいませーん etc. An example of checking if anybody is in a seemingly empty house is すいませーん。ごめんくださーい。だれかいますかー？(*Hi, Helloo, Is anybody there?*).

Perhaps in youtube videos they speak in the way of talking directly to listeners, so that you hear this kind of ー.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I didn't know that this thing had a official name! Also "vocative usage" as you point out i think exist in all language ahahah. Thanks!